# Ghost Touch Issue in Moto G4 Plus

Tags: touchscreen, charging, motorola

My mobile phone (Moto G4 Plus) shows Ghost Touch (erratic/random behavior) while charging. Other than the time of charging, the phone works normal.

In my view it is software issue. Require solutions of curbing this issue.

I have attached the Ghost Touch behavior Video for clarity of my issue.

Video Link Showing my Issue: [Ghost Touch Issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j83KB_4wwIo)

Comment: First thing is to change the charger and charging cable and report if the problem persists. Any standard 5V 2 A charger with it's cable would do. Is the video showing effect with Turbo charger?

Comment: This typically happens , when the voltage is high , as you may have noticed if you charged on *our* trains that provide charging outlets (yep, video shows your city :)

Comment: @beeshyams .Thanks for entertaining. Beside how can we solve such issues. Any Connector between charger and port, or any software that can manage that?

Comment: AFAIK ,  *unregulated*  voltage is the problem, not software/hardware. You can search net for *ghost touches* and you will find many pages leading to similar conclusion. Just change the charger and charging USB as suggested earlier and it should be fixed. Please revert with progress

Comment: @beeshyams, I too posted this question in the Lenovo forums, and they said that I need to go to a repair centre. I am too lazy to do that, giving my phone for weeks in hope for it to get it repaired. Someone said that the guys over there said that it was a motherboard issue. Can it be so?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan:  possible, but I know if you use a low power charger like 1A, it goes away, but charging takes much longer. BTW: That other question on PDF?

Comment: @beeshyams Okay, and yeah, the question which you suggested is what I am asking for, but I am not much into coding. Just wanted a software to do it for me, I.e no coding just simple clicks.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan: did you have a look at revised answer? I don't see any coding, is just using same so in two different ways

Answer (score 1):

It's hardware issue. You can try different cables or chargers, or contact manufacturer if your phone have warranty. Sure you always can turn off screen when charging ant don't use phone until it charges, but it's uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that's not a serious issue that may happen with any of the devices with touch display. I will not go in deep working of screens but the work with the potential difference generated by our touch or sticks/stylus.
The Turbo-Power brick which is bundled in the box is the culprit, (Only for those users who are facing ghost touch while charging.)
Hereby I will like to say that "You may try using a normal charger and that check if the problem persists."

P.S.- Those users who don't have ghost touch problem while using Turbo-Power brick they will experience the same after 8-10 months. So Prevention is always Better than cure..

And I think, That bundled brick is just for emergency usage..

You may go for Samsung/Micosoft micro-USB pinned charger, they are best in class..

Answer (score 0):

Set the brightness level at 10% - 60% then use your phone , ghost touch problem solved