# Nextbit robin not responding to my touch, instead tapping random places

Tags: touchscreen

I have a nextbit robin, but whenever I turn it on, things get selected. It's random where things are being selected for the most part, but it has been opening and selecting stuff in the bottom right corner quite a bit. I thought I saw something about "System UI not responding", but I'm not too sure. The top and bottom part are orange, otherwise nothing changed visually. Restarting the phone hasn't helped, and even in sleep mode it keeps doing stuff like turning on and off the flashlight. I did take it apart a few months ago to replace the battery, and the volume couldn't be redone. Not sure if that has anything to do with it, though

Comment: This is called "ghost touch" and is usually related to power/voltage issues (see [related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/152834/44325)), so the battery replacement might be a factor (is the spec the same as the stock battery for Nextbit Robin?).